# Por que não estou recebendo os dados da requisição?

Tags: php, laravel, angular

Tenho uma aplicação frontend Angular consumindo uma API Laravel. Nunca tive problemas assim em outros casos. Mas quando tento atualizar um registro, simplesmente não são enviados os dados ao Laravel. Mas se eu mudar a rota e colocar na rota de inserção funciona normal, envio para a aplicação um ícone e um nome de um assunto, mas as vezes pode cadastrar sem ícone.
Segue a classe de serviços do Angular, a subjectService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultService } from '../default/default.interface';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubjectService implements DefaultService {
  url = `${environment.url_api}/subject`;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public store(data:{name:string, icon?:any}):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/`, this.structuredData(data));
  }
  public getAll():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/`).pipe(
      map(
        (response:any) => response.data
      )
    );
  }
  public getById(id :number):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${id}`).pipe(
      map(
        (response:any) => response.data
      )
    );
  }
  public update(id:number, data:{name:string, icon?:any}):Observable<any>{
    console.log(this.structuredData(data));
    
    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${id}`, this.structuredData(data));
  }

  public structuredData(data:{name:string, icon?:any}) : any {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', data.name);
    if(data.icon !=undefined && data.icon !=null) formData.append('icon', data.icon, data.icon.name);
    return formData;
  }
}
```

O formulário está assim:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  <div class="row ">
    <form class="col s12" novalidate [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Editar assunto {{subject==null? '': subject.name}}</h4>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
            <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
            <label for="name" class="active">Nome*</label>
            <small *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid && form.get('name').touched" class="red-text">Este campo é
              obrigatório.</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col m12 s12 file-field input-field ">
            <div class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50"
              data-tooltip="Formatos aceitos: .jpg, .png, .jpeg">
              <span>Novo Ícone</span>
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="preparaUpload($event)">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path {{icon_error?'ng-invalid':''}}" type="text">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <small>Os campos com * são obrigatórios.</small>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <!--BUTTONS-->
        <div class="row" *ngIf="showSaveButton">
          <div class="col s12">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" [disabled]="isDisabled()">Salvar
              <i class="material-icons left">save</i>
            </button>

            <button href="#" class="btn grey waves-effect waves-light modal-action modal-close" (click)="voltar()"
              name="action">Voltar
              <i class="material-icons left">arrow_back</i>
            </button>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--END BUTTONS-->

        <div class="row" *ngIf="!showSaveButton">
          <!--PRELOADER-->
          <div class="col s12">
            <div class="preloader-wrapper small active">
              <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green-only">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gap-patch">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--END PRELOADER-->
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>


  </div>
  <swal #swal text="Ícone editado com sucesso" type="success" [showCancelButton]="false" [showConfirmButton]="false">
  </swal>
```

E o componente assim :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SwalComponent } from '@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { SubjectService } from 'src/app/core/services/subject/subject.service';
import { SubjectClass } from 'src/app/shared/models/subject.model';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-assunto-edit',
  templateUrl: './assunto-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assunto-edit.component.css']
})
export class AssuntoEditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private subjectService:SubjectService,
    private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

public form:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(191)]),
});
public showSaveButton = true;
public icon:any;
public subject:SubjectClass = null;
public id:number;

  ngOnInit() {
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
    
    $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: false, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
    }
    );
    $('#modal1').modal('open');
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params:Params)=>{
        this.id = params.id;
        this.subjectService.getById(params.id).subscribe(
          (subject:SubjectClass) => {
            this.subject = subject
            this.form.setValue({name:subject.name})
          }
          );
      }
    );

  }
  @ViewChild('swal') public swal:SwalComponent;

  preparaUpload(event:Event){
    this.icon = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).files[0]
  }
  isDisabled():string{
    return this.form.valid? '': 'disabled';
  }
  onSubmit(){
    
    if(this.form.valid){
      this.showSaveButton = false;
      let data:any = this.icon == undefined ? this.form.value : {name: this.form.value.name, icon:this.icon};
      this.subjectService.update(this.id, data).subscribe(
        ()=>{
          this.swal.show();

          setTimeout(()=>{
            $('#modal1').modal('close');
            this.voltar();
          }, 3000)
      },
      ()=>{
        
        
      }
      )

    }

  }
  public voltar(){
    this.router.navigate(['assunto']);
  }
}
```

O Controlador Laravel está assim:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    return response()->json(['request'=>$request->all()]);
    $subject = Subject::find($id);
    if(!$subject) return response()->json(['not_found'], 404);
    if($request->hasFile('icon')) $this->rules['icon.*'] = 'file|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg';
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only('name', 'icon'), $this->rules);
    if($validator->fails())return response()->json(['validation_error'], 400);

    if($request->hasFile('icon')){
        $extension = $request->icon->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = "{$subject->id}.{$extension}";
        $upload = $request->icon->storeAs("subject_icons", $name);
        if(!$upload) return response()->json(['error_upload'], 400);
        $subject->icon = $name;
    }
    $subject->name = $request->input('name');
    return  $subject->save() ? response()->json(['success']):response()->json(['error'], 400);
}
```

Coloquei esse primeiro return para verifica o que estava retornando nos valores da requisição. E retorna assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinceramente não faço a mínima ideia do que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui `'resolver'` o problema. Buscando sobre, isso parece ser um bug, como relatado pelos usuários no [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457). 
Para 'resolver', tive que trocar o método de envio para `POST`, e adicionar um campo `_method` na requisição passando o valor `PUT`. Parece que esse problema acontece ao enviar formulários `multipart/form-data`. Espero que ajude alguém.
O que mudou no serviço:

```
public update(id:number, data:{name:string, icon?:any}):Observable<any>{
    let newData:any = data;
    newData._method = 'PUT';
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${id}`, this.structuredData(newData));
  }

  public structuredData(data:{name:string, icon?:any, _method?:string}) : any {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', data.name);;
    if(data.icon !=undefined && data.icon !=null) formData.append('icon', data.icon, data.icon.name);
    if(data._method !=undefined && data._method !=null) formData.append('_method', data._method);
    return formData;
  }
```